# Looking for a shorter version of my filter function using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, reactjs, lodash

OK I have this working method to delete files if their id is in the array of Ids:

```
   deleteFiles(arrayOfIds) {
        let allFiles;
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfIds.length; i++) {
            allFiles = this.state.allFiles.filter((file) => {
                return file.id !== arrayOfIds[i];
            });
        }
        this.setState({allFiles});
    }
```

It works but what is the shorter version using only lodash or Vanilla JS?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
  deleteFiles(arrayOfIds) {
        this.setState({ 
           allFiles: this.state.allFiles.filter( 
              file=> arrayOfIds.indexOf(file.id) === -1 
        )});
  }
```

it uses `[].indexOf()` to avoid an inner loop, and inlines the other boilerplate to simplify the code.

Comment: I think you'd need `file.id` inside the `indexOf`

Comment: thanks @dandavis ... it works using return arrayOfIds.indexOf(file.id) === -1;

Comment: ahh, that detail was unclear because of how the filter in the for-loop in the question works, so i adjusted... i should read the english more often... ;)